# How can I show list of Images in vertical scroll view?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a list of images like this

```
  public Integer[] mImageIdsen = {
                    R.drawable.small,
                R.drawable.small,
                R.drawable.small,
                R.drawable.small,
                R.drawable.small,
                R.drawable.small};
```

and I want to show it in a linear vertical layout which is in a scrollview.
How can I assign this images to the vertical scroll list?
I can't put the xml code.

Comment: "If you can't put the xml code then we can throw in air." My dear, without knowing what problems you are getting and what you have implemented so far, how can we guess what problems you are facing.

Comment: use listview to display images in vertically. listview has functionality of scrollview. Use Adpter to set images in listview like: ListView lv = new ListView(this);
  lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, mImageIdsen));

Comment: you have a scrollView with an LinearLayout with an horizontal orientation . and then on your Code , create your ImageView on a loop for , and then , add them one by one to your LinearLayout by using the method : addView(imageView);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply scroll for parent layout in which u want to add your images vertically.

Comment: The issue in not to apply scrolling.I want to know how to put images this layout??

Comment: use custom list view as said by pavankumar

Comment: Thanks thiru for a supportive comment. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Custom list view is the best solution for the same. Override getview and add the images within it.

Comment: It's not so clear because I'm beginner .. how can I override getview??

Comment: GitHub: https://github.com/thest1/LazyList
 Source: http://open-pim.com/tmp/LazyList.zip

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Gallery` to display these. It's horizontal scrollable